# Different sized Thumbnails for first two Posts in a Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, thumbnails

I've been struggling to figure this out for several days now and though I haven't got it to work yet, you folks here at stackoverflow have been the most helpful so far.

To date, I've made 1 custom thumbnail in my functions.php and have been trying to use my theme options code for the other size.

Custom Thumbnail:
    `add_image_size('br-thumb', 623, 380, true );`

Theme Options Code:
        `<?php if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_post_content' ] != "content" ) woo_image( 'width='.$woo_options[ 'woo_thumb_w' ].'&height='.$woo_options[ 'woo_thumb_h'].'&class=thumbnail '.$woo_options[ 'woo_thumb_align' ]); ?>`

The custom is the one that I want for the first two.

I've tried several different loops with different ways of making separate code for the first post, but they were all written for changing only *1* post.  I used ones that had numbers in them, such as $i == 1 or $count == 1, so I could change them to == 2, but none of my attempts had any results.

I'm planning on using a category-ID.php file and stripping much of the other theme options from the loop, so have pretty much tried to build it from scratch.  The only difference between the posts would be the thumbnails.

Any ideas, super smart people of stackoverflow who have unknowingly saved my skin time and time again by their solutions?  :D

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    switch ( $wp_query->current_post ) {
        case 0 :
            // First image code here
            break;
        case 1 :
            // Second image code here
            break;
        default :
            // All other image code here
    }
endwhile;
```

Comment: Had to change it to `case 0` and `case 1`, but it worked **perfectly**!  Thank you so so much Jeff!!  Insanely simple, wickedly effective.  You're my hero of the week!